# Asynchronous AOF fsync is taking too long (disk is busy?). Writing the AOF buffer without waiting for fsync to complete, this may slow down Redis

Tags: redis, distributed-cache

I have run below Test-1 and Test-2 for longer run for performance test with redis configuration values specified, still we see the highlighted error-1 & 2 message and cluster is failing for some time, few of our processing failing. How to solve this problem.

please anyone have suggestion to avoid cluster fail which is goes longer than 10seconds, cluster is not coming up within 3 retry attempts (spring retry template we are using for retry mechanism try count is set to 3, and retry after 5sec, its exponential way next attempts) using Jedis client.

> > **Error-1:** Asynchronous AOF fsync is taking too long (disk is busy?). Writing the AOF buffer without waiting for fsync to complete, this may slow down Redis.
> >
> > **Error-2:** Marking node a523100ddfbf844c6d1cc7e0b6a4b3a2aa970aba as failing (quorum reached).

**Test-1:**

```
Run the test with Redis Setting: 

"appendfsync"="yes" 
"appendonly"="no"


[root@rdcapdev1-redis-cache3 redis-3.2.5]# src/redis-cli -p 6379

127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET **aof***

1) "auto-aof-rewrite-percentage"
2) "30"
3) "auto-aof-rewrite-min-size"
4) "67108864"
5) "aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync"
6) "yes"
7) "aof-load-truncated"
8) "yes"
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

```
[root@rdcapdev1-redis-cache3 redis-3.2.5]# src/redis-cli -p 6380

127.0.0.1:6380> CONFIG GET **aof***

1) "auto-aof-rewrite-percentage"
2) "30"
3) "auto-aof-rewrite-min-size"
4) "67108864"
5) "aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync"
6) "yes"
7) "aof-load-truncated"
8) "yes"
127.0.0.1:6380> clear
```

**Observation:**

```
  1. The redis failover occurred for ~40 sec.
  2. There are around 20 documents failed on FX and OCR level. Due to inability to write/read the files to Redis.
  3. This has been happened when ~50% of RAM got utilized.
  4. The Master-slave configuration has be reshuffled as below after this failover.
  5. Below are the few highlights of the redis log, plese refer that attached log for more detail.
  6. I have logs for this, for more details: 30Per_AofRW_2.zip
```

**Redis1 Master log:**

```
2515:C 05 May 11:06:30.343 * DB saved on disk
2515:C 05 May 11:06:30.379 * RDB: 15 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
837:S 05 May 11:06:30.429 * Background saving terminated with success
837:S 05 May 11:11:31.024 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
837:S 05 May 11:11:31.067 * Background saving started by pid 2534
837:S 05 May 11:12:24.802 * FAIL message received from 6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 about ce62a26102ef54f43fa7cca64d24eab45cf42a61
837:S 05 May 11:12:27.049 * Clear FAIL state for node ce62a26102ef54f43fa7cca64d24eab45cf42a61: slave is reachable again.
2534:C 05 May 11:12:31.110 * DB saved on disk
```

**Redis2 Master log:**

```
837:M 05 May 10:30:22.216 * Marking node a523100ddfbf844c6d1cc7e0b6a4b3a2aa970aba as failing (quorum reached).
837:M 05 May 10:30:22.216 # Cluster state changed: fail
837:M 05 May 10:30:23.148 # Failover auth granted to 6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 for epoch 12
837:M 05 May 10:30:23.188 # Cluster state changed: ok
837:M 05 May 10:30:27.227 * Clear FAIL state for node a523100ddfbf844c6d1cc7e0b6a4b3a2aa970aba: slave is reachable again.
837:M 05 May 10:35:22.017 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
.
.
.
837:M 05 May 11:12:23.592 * FAIL message received from 6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 about ce62a26102ef54f43fa7cca64d24eab45cf42a61
837:M 05 May 11:12:27.045 * Clear FAIL state for node ce62a26102ef54f43fa7cca64d24eab45cf42a61: slave is reachable again.
```

**Redis3 Master Log:**

```
833:M 05 May 10:30:22.217 * FAIL message received from 83f6a9589aa1bce8932a367894fa391edd0ce269 about a523100ddfbf844c6d1cc7e0b6a4b3a2aa970aba
833:M 05 May 10:30:22.217 # Cluster state changed: fail
833:M 05 May 10:30:23.149 # Failover auth granted to 6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 for epoch 12
833:M 05 May 10:30:23.189 # Cluster state changed: ok
1822:C 05 May 10:30:27.397 * DB saved on disk
1822:C 05 May 10:30:27.428 * RDB: 8 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
833:M 05 May 10:30:27.528 * Background saving terminated with success
833:M 05 May 10:30:27.828 * Clear FAIL state for node a523100ddfbf844c6d1cc7e0b6a4b3a2aa970aba: slave is reachable again.

HOST: localhost PORT: 6379
machine master slave
10.2.1.233 0.00 2.00
10.2.1.46 2.00 0.00
10.2.1.202 1.00 1.00

MASTER SLAVE INFO
hashCode master slave hashSlot
81ae2d757f57f36fa1df6e930af3b072084ba3e8 10.2.1.202:6379 10.2.1.233:6380, 10923-16383
6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 10.2.1.46:6380 10.2.1.233:6379, 0-5460
83f6a9589aa1bce8932a367894fa391edd0ce269 10.2.1.46:6379 10.2.1.202:6380, 5461-10922
6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 10.2.1.46:6380 master - 0 1493981044497 12 connected 0-5460
81ae2d757f57f36fa1df6e930af3b072084ba3e8 10.2.1.202:6379 master - 0 1493981045500 3 connected 10923-16383
ce62a26102ef54f43fa7cca64d24eab45cf42a61 10.2.1.202:6380 slave 83f6a9589aa1bce8932a367894fa391edd0ce269 0 1493981043495 10 connected
ac630108d1556786a4df74945cfe35db981d15fa 10.2.1.233:6380 slave 81ae2d757f57f36fa1df6e930af3b072084ba3e8 0 1493981042492 11 connected
83f6a9589aa1bce8932a367894fa391edd0ce269 10.2.1.46:6379 master - 0 1493981044497 2 connected 5461-10922
a523100ddfbf844c6d1cc7e0b6a4b3a2aa970aba 10.2.1.233:6379 myself,slave 6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 0 0 1 connected
```

**Test-2:**

```
Run the test with Redis Setting: 

"appendfsync"="no" 
"appendonly"="yes"
```

**Observation:**

```
1. The redis failover occurred for ~40 sec.
2. There are around 20 documents failed on FX and OCR level. Due to inability to write/read the files to Redis.
3. This has been happened when ~50% of RAM got utilized.
4. The Master-slave configuration has be reshuffled as below after this failover.
5. Below are the few highlights of the redis log, plese refer that attached log for more detail.
30Per_AofRW_2.zip
```

**Redis1 Master log:**

```
2515:C 05 May 11:06:30.343 * DB saved on disk
2515:C 05 May 11:06:30.379 * RDB: 15 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
837:S 05 May 11:06:30.429 * Background saving terminated with success
837:S 05 May 11:11:31.024 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
837:S 05 May 11:11:31.067 * Background saving started by pid 2534
837:S 05 May 11:12:24.802 * FAIL message received from 6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 about ce62a26102ef54f43fa7cca64d24eab45cf42a61
837:S 05 May 11:12:27.049 * Clear FAIL state for node ce62a26102ef54f43fa7cca64d24eab45cf42a61: slave is reachable again.
2534:C 05 May 11:12:31.110 * DB saved on disk
```

**Redis2 Master log:**

```
5306:M 03 Apr 09:02:36.947 * Background saving terminated with success
5306:M 03 Apr 09:02:49.574 * Starting automatic rewriting of AOF on 3% growth
5306:M 03 Apr 09:02:49.583 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 12864
5306:M 03 Apr 09:02:54.050 * AOF rewrite child asks to stop sending diffs.
12864:C 03 Apr 09:02:54.051 * Parent agreed to stop sending diffs. Finalizing AOF...
12864:C 03 Apr 09:02:54.051 * Concatenating 0.00 MB of AOF diff received from parent.
12864:C 03 Apr 09:02:54.051 * SYNC append only file rewrite performed
12864:C 03 Apr 09:02:54.058 * AOF rewrite: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
5306:M 03 Apr 09:02:54.098 * Background AOF rewrite terminated with success
5306:M 03 Apr 09:02:54.098 * Residual parent diff successfully flushed to the rewritten AOF (0.00 MB)
5306:M 03 Apr 09:02:54.098 * Background AOF rewrite finished successfully
5306:M 03 Apr 09:04:01.843 * Starting automatic rewriting of AOF on 3% growth
5306:M 03 Apr 09:04:01.853 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 12867
5306:M 03 Apr 09:04:11.657 * AOF rewrite child asks to stop sending diffs.
12867:C 03 Apr 09:04:11.657 * Parent agreed to stop sending diffs. Finalizing AOF...
12867:C 03 Apr 09:04:11.657 * Concatenating 0.00 MB of AOF diff received from parent.
12867:C 03 Apr 09:04:11.657 * SYNC append only file rewrite performed
12867:C 03 Apr 09:04:11.664 * AOF rewrite: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
5306:M 03 Apr 09:04:11.675 * Background AOF rewrite terminated with success
5306:M 03 Apr 09:04:11.675 * Residual parent diff successfully flushed to the rewritten AOF (0.00 MB)
5306:M 03 Apr 09:04:11.675 * Background AOF rewrite finished successfully
5306:M 03 Apr 09:04:48.054 * Asynchronous AOF fsync is taking too long (disk is busy?). Writing the AOF buffer without waiting for fsync to complete, this may slow down Redis.
5306:M 03 Apr 09:05:28.571 * Starting automatic rewriting of AOF on 3% growth
5306:M 03 Apr 09:05:28.581 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 12873
5306:M 03 Apr 09:05:33.300 * AOF rewrite child asks to stop sending diffs.
12873:C 03 Apr 09:05:33.300 * Parent agreed to stop sending diffs. Finalizing AOF...
12873:C 03 Apr 09:05:33.300 * Concatenating 2.09 MB of AOF diff received from parent.
12873:C 03 Apr 09:05:33.329 * SYNC append only file rewrite performed
12873:C 03 Apr 09:05:33.336 * AOF rewrite: 11 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
5306:M 03 Apr 09:05:33.395 * Background AOF rewrite terminated with success
5306:M 03 Apr 09:05:33.395 * Residual parent diff successfully flushed to the rewritten AOF (0.00 MB)
5306:M 03 Apr 09:05:33.395 * Background AOF rewrite finished successfully
5306:M 03 Apr 09:07:37.082 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
5306:M 03 Apr 09:07:37.092 * Background saving started by pid 12875
12875:C 03 Apr 09:07:47.016 * DB saved on disk
12875:C 03 Apr 09:07:47.024 * RDB: 5 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
5306:M 03 Apr 09:07:47.113 * Background saving terminated with success
5306:M 03 Apr 09:07:51.622 * Starting automatic rewriting of AOF on 3% growth
5306:M 03 Apr 09:07:51.632 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 12876
5306:M 03 Apr 09:07:56.559 * AOF rewrite child asks to stop sending diffs.
12876:C 03 Apr 09:07:56.559 * Parent agreed to stop sending diffs. Finalizing AOF...
12876:C 03 Apr 09:07:56.559 * Concatenating 0.00 MB of AOF diff received from parent.
12876:C 03 Apr 09:07:56.559 * SYNC append only file rewrite performed
12876:C 03 Apr 09:07:56.567 * AOF rewrite: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
5306:M 03 Apr 09:07:56.645 * Background AOF rewrite terminated with success
5306:M 03 Apr 09:07:56.645 * Residual parent diff successfully flushed to the rewritten AOF (0.00 MB)
5306:M 03 Apr 09:07:56.645 * Background AOF rewrite finished successfully
5306:M 03 Apr 09:12:48.071 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
5306:M 03 Apr 09:12:48.081 * Background saving started by pid 12882
12882:C 03 Apr 09:12:58.381 * DB saved on disk
12882:C 03 Apr 09:12:58.389 * RDB: 5 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
5306:M 03 Apr 09:12:58.403 * Background saving terminated with success
5306:M 03 Apr 10:17:33.005 * Asynchronous AOF fsync is taking too long (disk is busy?). Writing the AOF buffer without waiting for fsync to complete, this may slow down Redis.
5306:M 03 Apr 10:22:42.042 * Asynchronous AOF fsync is taking too long (disk is busy?). Writing the AOF buffer without waiting for fsync to complete, this may slow down Redis.
5306:M 03 Apr 10:27:51.039 * Asynchronous AOF fsync is taking too long (disk is busy?). Writing the AOF buffer without waiting for fsync to complete, this may slow down Redis.
5306:M 03 Apr 11:10:10.606 * Marking node a523100ddfbf844c6d1cc7e0b6a4b3a2aa970aba as failing (quorum reached).
5306:M 03 Apr 11:10:10.607 # Cluster state changed: fail
5306:M 03 Apr 11:10:10.608 * FAIL message received from 83f6a9589aa1bce8932a367894fa391edd0ce269 about ac630108d1556786a4df74945cfe35db981d15fa
5306:M 03 Apr 11:10:11.594 # Failover auth granted to 6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 for epoch 7

HOST: localhost PORT: 6379
machine master slave
10.2.1.233 0.00 2.00
10.2.1.46 2.00 0.00
10.2.1.202 1.00 1.00
```

**MASTER SLAVE INFO**

```
hashCode master slave hashSlot
81ae2d757f57f36fa1df6e930af3b072084ba3e8 10.2.1.202:6379 10.2.1.233:6380, 10923-16383
6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 10.2.1.46:6380 10.2.1.233:6379, 0-5460
83f6a9589aa1bce8932a367894fa391edd0ce269 10.2.1.46:6379 10.2.1.202:6380, 5461-10922
6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 10.2.1.46:6380 master - 0 1493981044497 12 connected 0-5460
81ae2d757f57f36fa1df6e930af3b072084ba3e8 10.2.1.202:6379 master - 0 1493981045500 3 connected 10923-16383
ce62a26102ef54f43fa7cca64d24eab45cf42a61 10.2.1.202:6380 slave 83f6a9589aa1bce8932a367894fa391edd0ce269 0 1493981043495 10 connected
ac630108d1556786a4df74945cfe35db981d15fa 10.2.1.233:6380 slave 81ae2d757f57f36fa1df6e930af3b072084ba3e8 0 1493981042492 11 connected
83f6a9589aa1bce8932a367894fa391edd0ce269 10.2.1.46:6379 master - 0 1493981044497 2 connected 5461-10922
a523100ddfbf844c6d1cc7e0b6a4b3a2aa970aba 10.2.1.233:6379 myself,slave 6b8d49e9db288b13071559c667e95e3691ce8bd0 0 0 1 connected
```

Comment: Perhaps post this at the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/)?