# What does "quorum reached" in redis logs? what technically it means?

Tags: redis, distributed-caching, redis-cache

What does "quorum reached" in redis logs technically what it indicates, is it problem? Am I missing anything to tuning in redis.conf parameter to fix it?

**Redis log message:**

```
Marking node a523100ddfbf844c6d1cc7e0b6a4b3a2aa970aba as failing (quorum reached).
837:M 05 May 10:30:22.216 # Cluster state changed: fail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message means that the cluster had reached a consensus about that node's status and it is marked as failing. This happens when a node does not respond to the cluster's internal chatter protocol, and could be the result of any kind of failure (e.g. network, process...). You should check that node's logs for more information.

Comment: I have posted detailed logs with my observation, if you could go through that and help me understand the resolution to that redis problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693975/asynchronous-aof-fsync-is-taking-too-long-disk-is-busy-writing-the-aof-buffe]